# Multiple 'OR' using ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, dplyr

I would like to make the several 'OR' conditions like this:

```
 dta_EARTHQbb <- dta_EARTHQb %>%
      mutate(ASS = ifelse(CODE=="01"|CODE=="02"|CODE=="03", 1, 0))
```

If the CODE is 01, or 02, or 03, it attached '1' otherwise '0'.

I want to make another approach as the conditions are larger 
like this:

```
    CONDITONa = c(01,02,03)  
dta_EARTHQbb <- dta_EARTHQb %>%
          mutate(ASS = ifelse(CODE==CONDITIONa, 1, 0))
```

Howev..., it does not work.. How do I adjust this code..?

Comment: `ifelse(CODE %in% c("01","02","03"), 1, 0)`.

Comment: Or, for larger numbers of conditions, something like this: `library(stringr); ifelse(CODE %in% str_pad(1:50, 2, "left", 0), 1, 0)`.

Comment: When there is more than one set of *true* / *false* options, I also like to use `dplyr::case_when`... however, I would say the first comment by @eipi10 seems most appropriate here

Comment: Or even better, `as.integer(CODE %in% c("01","02","03"))`. No need for `ifelse`.

Comment: If you have defined `CONDITIONa = c("01","02","03")` variable, then you could also refer to it: `ifelse(CODE %in% CONDITIONa, 1, 0)`.